# Split on period but ignore some words which contains period in java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I want to split a document into paragraphs, for that, I am using.

> String paragraphs[] = documentData.split("\.\n");

but it removes **.\n** from the actual document. I don't want to lose those tokens. Also, I want that, words like **Inc. etc. Jr.** should not be split by the regular expression.

Comment: Do all of your sentences have two spaces after each period (full stop)?  The first part of your question is easy, the second not so much.  You would need to either hard code every possible abbreviation, or tell us how we can distinguish a full stop from other types of periods.

Comment: Nasty edge case: What if a sentence ends in `Jr.`, e.g. `I like Ken Griffey Jr.` ... in this case, even excluding certain abbreviations would fail.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: If a sentence ends with Jr. then It should not be broken.

Comment: You're going to have to provide some logic as to how to detect the end of a sentence.  Otherwise, I'd say that your question is too broad.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question: a text should be broken on period but if period occurs after certain words like Jr. etc. or Inc. then it should not be split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic script just to point you in the right direction:

```
String input = "Sentence one in paragraph one.  Sentence two in paragraph one.\n Sentence one in paragraph two.  Sentence two in paragraph two.";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<=\\.\n)\\s*");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

One way to split on dot while not consuming it is to use a lookarounds.  Lookarounds match, but do not consume, making them ideal for what you have in mind.  In this case, I am splitting on the following pattern:

```
(?<=\.\n)\s*
```

This asserts that what comes before the current position is a full stop followed by a newline.  Then it consumes any whitespace which might separate paragraphs, before printing the paragraph to the console.

### Demo

Comment: I want to split on period followed by new line (.\n), for that I have used 
**String input = "Hello World. The Jr. baker was here last night. Mr. bear also stopped by.\n This is another sentence.";
String[] parts = input.split("(?<!(?:Jr.|Mr.))(?<=\\.\n)");**

but the output is:
**parts[0] = "Hello World. The Jr. baker was here last night. Mr. bear also stopped by."
parts[1] = "\n"
parts[2] = "This is another sentence."**

I want output like below:
**parts[0] = "Hello World. The Jr. baker was here last night. Mr. bear also stopped by.\n"
parts[1] = "This is another sentence."**

Comment: @SandeepJoshi Check my updated answer, your comment made me realize I was overthinking the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the final regex and demo.